# With d3.js, how can I use the same script to create 3 charts with 3 datasources?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Imagine I have an index.html with #chart1 #chart2 and #chart3

I want to populate those three charts with three different data files, but using the same script.

Currently I just have the script copied 3 times in my script file, with the necessary updates made (i.e. swapping out #chart1 for #chart2 and 1.tsv1 for 2.tsv etc...

How can I do this more intelligently/elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excellent tutorial by Mike Bostock outlining one possible way of doing this can be found here: [Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)

To try and summarize briefly, it proposes a standard way of defining reusable charts that fit nicely into the way D3 handles data and selections.  First you define your chart:

```
function reusableChart() {
  //variables, etc.

  function my() {
    // chart generation code
  }

  //getter-setter methods

  return my;
}
```

You then would instantiate this chart generator, select elements and bind data to them in the usual D3 way, and finally call the generator function:

```
var myChart = reusableChart().setValue("example", 0);

d3.tsv("1.tsv", function(error, data) {
  d3.select("#chart1").datum(data).call(myChart);
});
//etc..
```

Comment: In particular with the pattern Mike proposes, you can also do all charts at once: `d3.select("#container").data([chart1, chart2, chart3]).enter().append("svg")...`.